# How to handle Django connection loss with database gracefully?

Tags: django, oracle

I am no database expert. I need a very basic solution to handle Django connection loss with my Oracle database. I want to handle the exception and display overall site and empty tables with message that db connection is lost.

What is the most painless way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 'try: except:'  why are you using oracle if you are "no database expert".

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I handle the front end part for a small project.

Comment: Well then backend stuff is not your problem. Ask backend guys to return some error code when the DB connection is lost.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyShipilov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to do it; but I think you are asking the wrong question.

Roughly, [handler500](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/#handler500) does what you want. However, this is called on every internal server error, and it doesn't have a way of knowing what the error was. But here is why I think that your question is wrong: why does the user care? All the user needs to know is that your server is malfunctioning; why would they care whether the problem is the connection to the database, or a filesystem error, or a bug in your app?

Finally, my opinion is to not mess up with handler500. If you try to do smart things when a fatal error has occurred, you are asking for trouble. Instead, I would suggest to do nothing more than create a nice `500.html`.